# Есть ли какая-то разница в коде? Один работает, а второй нет

Tags: javascript

Есть ли какая-то разница между ними? Вроде абсолютно одинаковые, но второй не работает.
Подскажите, в чем причина?

Это первый код

```
function getNums(string) {
    return (string.split(/[\ \-\+\*\/]+/));
}

function getOperator(string) {
    let operatorIndex = string.search(/[-\+\*\/]/);
    return (string[operatorIndex]);
}

function calc(nums, operator) {
    nums.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item < 1 || item > 10) {
            throw new Error();
        }
    });
    switch (operator) {
        case '-':
            return (nums[0] - nums[1]);
        case '+':
            return (Number(nums[0]) + Number(nums[1]));
        case '*':
            return (nums[0] * nums[1]);
        case '/':
            return (nums[0] / nums[1]);
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}

function toArabic(roman) {
    roman = roman.toUpperCase();
    let lookup = {
            I: 1,
            V: 5,
            X: 10,
            L: 50,
            C: 100,
            D: 500,
            M: 1000
        },
        arabic = 0,
        i = roman.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (lookup[roman[i]] < lookup[roman[i + 1]]) 
        arabic -= lookup[roman[i]];
        else arabic += lookup[roman[i]];
    }
    return arabic;
}

function toRoman(num) {
    let lookup = {
            M: 1000,
            CM: 900,
            D: 500,
            CD: 400,
            C: 100,
            XC: 90,
            L: 50,
            XL: 40,
            X: 10,
            IX: 9,
            V: 5,
            IV: 4,
            I: 1
        },
        roman = '',
        i;
    for (i in lookup) {
        while (num >= lookup[i]) {
            roman += i;
            num -= lookup[i];
        }
    }
    return roman;
}

function calculator(string) {
    let nums = getNums(string);
    if (nums.length != 2) throw new Error();
    let operator = getOperator(string);
    let result;
    if (Number(nums[0]) && Number(nums[1])) {
        result = Math.floor(calc(nums, operator));
    } else
    if (!Number(nums[0]) && !Number(nums[1])) {
        let arabicNums = [toArabic(nums[0]), toArabic(nums[1])];
        result = toRoman(Number(calc(arabicNums, operator)));
    } else {
        throw new Error();
    }
    return (String(result));
}
```

Вот второй

```
function getNums(string) {
    return (string.split(/[\ \-\+\*\/]+/));
}

function getOperator(string) {
    let operatorIndex = string.search(/[-\+\*\/]/);
    return (string[operatorIndex]);
}

function calc(nums, operator) {
    nums.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item < 1 || item > 10) {
            throw new Error();
        }
    });
    switch (operator) {
        case '-':
            return (nums[0] - nums[1]);
        case '+':
            return (Number(nums[0]) + Number(nums[1]));
        case '/':
            return (nums[0] / nums[1]);
        case '*':
            return (nums[0] * nums[1]);
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}

function toArabic(roman) {
    roman = roman.toUpperCase();
    let lookup = {
            I: 1,
            V: 5,
            X: 10,
            L: 50,
            C: 100,
            D: 500,
            M: 1000
        },
        arabic = 0,
        i = roman.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (lookup[roman[1]] < lookup[roman[i + 1]]) 
        arabic -= lookup[roman[i]];
        else arabic += lookup[roman[i]];
    }
    return arabic;
}

function toRoman(num) {
    let lookup = {
            M: 1000,
            CM: 900,
            D: 500,
            CD: 400,
            C: 100,
            XC: 90,
            L: 50,
            XL: 40,
            X: 10,
            IX: 9,
            V: 5,
            IV: 4,
            I: 1
        },
        roman = '',
        i;
    for (i in lookup) {
        while (num >= lookup[i]) {
            roman += i;
            num -= lookup[i];
        }
    }
    return roman;
}

function calculator(string) {
    let nums = getNums(string);
    if (nums.length != 2) throw new Error();
    let operator = getOperator(string);
    let result;
    if (Number(nums[0]) && Number(nums[1])) {
        result = Math.floor(calc(nums, operator));
    } else
    if (!Number(nums[0]) && !Number(nums[1])) {
        let arabicNums = [toArabic(nums[0]), toArabic(nums[1])];
        result = toRoman(Number(calc(arabicNums, operator)));
    } else {
        throw new Error();
    }
    return (String(result));
}
```

Comment: Это такая игра - "Найдите отличия"?

Comment: Это называется "помоги товарищу найти косяк". Че то у вас тут самое злое сообщество, вопрос задать нельзя.

Comment: Можно было комментами / стрелочками указать, где конкретно изменен код. Чтобы остальным не пришлось бегать глазами и посимвольно всё сравнивать.

Comment: Сравнить два куска текста Вы можете и сами. Визуально или код для этого написать. Если они действительно "абсолютно одинаковые", значит дело не в них. Но в вопросе больше ничего нет.

Comment: Код написан по подобию и нигде не изменен, проверяла уже много раз. Вот попросила помощи, может где увидите косяк. А так, помощь тут вроде добровольная.

Comment: Да, и добровольцев изучать 200 строк кода даже здесь не будет.

Comment: `\`код1\`.replace(/\s/g, "") == \`код2\`replace(/\s/g, "")` — false, очевидно, разница есть)

Comment: Ну не будет и не будет, вся инфа эта мне ни к чему. Если что-то дельное есть сказать, пишите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код не *нигде не изменен*. Что я смог увидеть сразу, так это в функции `function toArabic(roman) {}` в первом случае:

```
if (lookup[roman[i]] < lookup[roman[i + 1]]) // сравнение с каждым i-тым
```

во втором:

```
 if (lookup[roman[1]] < lookup[roman[i + 1]]) // сравнение с первым
```

Comment: Сравнил два файла программно. Это единственная существенная разница. Вторая не такая важная — переставлены местами два `case` в `switch`.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, тоже увидел, не стал писать